# UITableView Problem: Not able to display dynamic data with UIColor in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, cells

I am working with the UITableView where i am getting the data from the file and displaying that data with the **UItableview**.  What i did was i placed the data in the **UILabel** and then i added this label to the contentview.  This is working fine.  But when i change the color of the label text to blue and then i moved from the first few cells towards the end and what i found was that the text is being **overlapped**.  Everything seems to be blue and i am not able to see the text.  Is there anything i am missing?. i used **reloaddata** also but its not working.

Thanks in advance,
Aby

Comment: Problem is Solved.  I have added the label for the other content where i was getting problem.  So the text is not getting overlapped with labels.

Comment: Rather than putting "Solved" in the title, which is discouraged, write your solution as an answer and accept it yourself.  This will better show that the problem is solved, and how you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the label for the other content where i was getting problem. So the text is not getting overlapped with labels